# What is 'Depth' in Image Processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing

When I develop Image Processing Program to use OpenCV, I can usually see '**`IPL_DEPTH_8U`**' or '**`IPL_DEPTH_16U`**'

But, I don't know what does that mean.

What is the meaning of '**Depth**' in the context of Image Processing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depth is the "precision" of each pixel. Typically it can be 8/24/32 bit for displaying, but any precision for computations.

Instead of precision you can also call it the data type of the pixel. The more bits per element, the better to represent different colors or intensities.

Your examples mean:
`8U` : 8 bit per element (maybe 8 bit per channel if multiple channels) of unsigned integer type. So probably you can access elements as `unsigned char` values, because that's 8 bit unsigned type.

`16U` : 16 bit per element => `unsigned short` is typically the 16 bit unsigned integer type on your system.

In OpenCV you typically have those types:

`8UC3` : 8 bit unsigned and 3 channels => 24 bit per pixel in total.

`8UC1` : 8 bit unsigned with a single channel

`32S`: 32 bit integer type => `int`

`32F`: 32 bit floating point => `float`

`64F`: 64 bit floating point => `double`

hope this helps